# How does routing work in backbone.js using the onclick event?

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

I have a DIV, which contains a label with the user's name. The onclick event is bound to that DIV.

I want that user's name to append with URL of the current page.

My user's name is in a model.

I have read about backbone.js router & seen some examples also but those example use the A tag for routing, which uses whatever is there in its attribute HREF.

But I want it to be done on a DIV's click.

I have started reading backbone.js 2 days ago so I am not getting how to achieve this.
What should be my approach to get it done? Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also manually navigate in code using the router's [navigate](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Router-navigate) method,

```
$('#yourDiv').bind('click', function(e) {
 yourRouter.navigate("aroute/something", {trigger: true});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Jacks example is good, but perhaps a less coupled example would be:

`window.location = window.location.hash + model.get('userName')`

you don't need a reference to the router, or to know the current 'base' route